# Run part of controller code every time a page is navigated to in Ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In my controller below, the datapoint seems to only load data from the service the first time this page is opened. The next time it doesn't. At least that's how I have concluded it works.

What is a good way to make it get data from the service every time the page is loaded?

```
(function(){
  angular.module('appname')
    .controller('EnterValueCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$filter', '$translate', 'SharedPropertiesSrvc',
      function($scope, $state, $filter, $translate, SharedPropertiesSrvc) {

        $scope.datapoint = {
          value: SharedPropertiesSrvc.datapoint.value,
          inputType: SharedPropertiesSrvc.datapoint.inputType
        };

      }]);
})();
```

Here is my service code:

```
(function(){
  angular.module('appname')
    .factory('SharedPropertiesSrvc', [
      function(){
        return {
          datapoint: {
            inputType: '',
            value: ''
          }
      };
      }])
})();
```

Comment: it should load everytime. Can you share your service code?

Comment: @TarunDugar: I've added the service code to the OP

Comment: I think the code is fine and should load the data everytime in the controller. Try putting a console.log inside the service and see if its running everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a great answer here:

> http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-excecute-the-controller-every-time/14893/3

I used

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function() {
    //runs every time the page activates
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is evaluated only the first time you load that controller, to reload data every time you go to that state you could listen `$stateChangeStart` or `$stateChangeSuccess`.

something like this:

```
 $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
        function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
          if (toState.name === "YourStateName") {
            $scope.datapoint = {
              value: SharedPropertiesSrvc.datapoint.value,
              inputType: SharedPropertiesSrvc.datapoint.inputType
            };
          }
        }
      );
```

Comment: Where should I put that code? I tried putting it at the end of the controller I posted and it never runs. changed "YourStateName" to match the state connected to that controller.

Comment: you should put that code in the controller instead of  "$scope.datapoint = {
          value: SharedPropertiesSrvc.datapoint.value,
          inputType: SharedPropertiesSrvc.datapoint.inputType
        };"

Comment: Thank you! I still have trouble getting it to work. Should I inject '$stateChangeStart into my controller? When I try to inject it I get unknown injector error. When I don't inject it, the event never triggers.